# To extract a string

Tags: python, regex

Here i want to extract just the **alpitananad** from the email id. This much i have done so far.

```
import re

def extracter(text):
        reg1 = re.compile(r'(\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))?(\s|-|\.)?(\d{3})(\s|-|\.)(\d{4})')
        se1 = reg1.findall(text)
        print(se1)
        for i in range(len(se1)):
               print(''.join(se1[i]))
        reg2 = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z0-9]+@+[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})')
        reg3 = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]+@')
        se3 = reg3.findall(text)
        se2 = reg2.findall(text)
        print(se2)
        print(se3)

text1 = "123-434-2432 of may name is jsdiofhsdio fh diofh dui fjf ui834y8  fwe8fweuihwe 8f e87f y87 456-243-3434 ajsfhj alpitanand20@gamil.com"
extracter(text1)
```

The output i am getting is

```
[('123', '-', '434', '-', '2432'), ('456', '-', '243', '-', '3434')]
123-434-2432
456-243-3434
['alpitanand20@gamil.com']
['alpitanand20@']
```

i want one output just to check the give the previous string of **@**. What changes should i make in reg3. Thank You..!!!

Comment: See https://ideone.com/a79CE5

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you are after, but... `findall` returns a list of found values (just like the name suggests). So taking your question very specifically you might want to consider `reg3.findall(text)[0]`

Comment: Solution is given...thanks for help..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
re.findall('(\w+)@', text1)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> text1 = "123-434-2432 of may name is jsdiofhsdio fh diofh dui fjf ui834y8  fwe8fweuihwe 8f e87f y87 456-243-3434 ajsfhj alpitanand20@gamil.com"
>>> reg3 = re.compile(r'(\w+)@')
>>> se3 = reg3.findall(text1)
>>> se3
['alpitanand20']
```